Next JS. Clerk Auth User Roles
I use clerk for authentication.And I want to add a role function (for example, administrator and moderator) with different access levels
I have read the official documentation
Еhe documentation suggests user search (I still don’t understand how it works). But I need to organize this differently. I want to have a table with all ever registered users and the ability to change their rights.


wrote 1v1 with documentation
